# Disable a drive for a specific user

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive, users, user-management

I've just made a new user account for a friend of mine. But I don't want him to have access to my data drive ( it's not the drive where ubuntu is installed on but just a data drive ).

How can I disable that drive for him?

I'm using ubuntu 14.04.

EDIT:

blkid:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="eee523f2-0eb4-4ee8-b758-f8ea89273233" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="69b06774-64ed-4c11-b157-5a794c20c98c" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb2: UUID="5E521E0E521DEC11" TYPE="ntfs"
```

lsblk:

[image]

EDIT:

```
basement21@basement21:~$ groups basement21
basement21 : basement21 adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare secretdrive
basement21@basement21:~$ groups planner
planner : planner
basement21@basement21:~$
```

Comment: what type is it? (ntfs/ext4)

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: if you run `sudo blkid` you can find out.

Comment: also, what is its mountpoint? (run `lsblk`)

Comment: I've edited my post with the output of these commands. It my /mnt/data I want to disable for that user.

Comment: I'm going to try this evening :-) and let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search I've found what the problem was. When I installed my system I added this line in my fstab:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/5E521E0E521DEC11 /mnt/data auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

I changed it to:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/5E521E0E521DEC11 /mnt/data auto nosuid,nodev,gid=1000,umask=007,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

My groupid is 1000 and the umask defines I've got the reading/write permission and everyone in my group too. The rest has no permission.

Comment: "After a long search I've found what the problem was". I am not sure I understand: *which* problem?. You must be referring to one of the other answers?

Comment: Yes, because of that line it was ALWAYS mounted even when I created a separate account for the drive and add a group to it. So thats why you must add gid and umask. If you don't the fstab overwrites the group thing that Faron and Madneon gave as solution.

Comment: Not my case, but what you actually say is that either one of their solution works. IMO would be nicer to give (either one) the credits and add your comment why it didn't work at first.

Answer (score 2):

Change `/mnt/data` **owner** and **group** to yourself like this:

```
sudo chown basement21.basement21 /mnt/data
```

And allow only you to **read** and **write**, and your personal group to **only read**:

```
sudo chmod 750 /mnt/data
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the desire result as you indicated:

Call your system to recognize /dev/sdb to belong to you:

```
sudo adduser secretdrive
sudo chown secretdrive:secretdrive /dev/sdb
sudo adduser [your-username] secretdrive
sudo chmod 770 /dev/sdb
```

Explanation:

1. assign a new system name to your drive: `/dev/sdb`
2. chown-ize your drive to the system username of `secretdrive` (or
   whichever name you want)
3. add your username to the group belonging to `secretdrive` so that
   way system will grant you the access to the drive
4. finally, you chmod-ize your drive to 770 (read/write by owner |
   read/write by group | no-read/no-write to rest of everybody else)

Comment: sorry for the late response. It doesn't work. I did everything you said but when I add another user for my friend and I login on his account he still sees my secretdrive. Do I need to change something? I set my drive to automatically mount is that a problem? Please check my edit. Planner is the account for my friend. Thanks for all your effort btw

Answer (score 1):

The solution below assumes your *friend* is not an expert, trying to hack your computer to find a way to look into your data. It is however a reasonable threshold, to prevent unintended access (mounting) to a specific partition or drive.

---

An option, that also can be used as a more *temporary* solution on any user account is the following:

1. Add the following to the `sudoers` file (`/etc/sudoers`, running `sudo visudo`):

   ```
   <your_friends_username> ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/umount
   ```

   This will enable him to *unmount* a drive without sudo password
2. In your friends' account, copy the script below into an empty file and save it somewhere as `nomount.py` (or better, a less revealing name :) )
3. Test-run (still in your friends' account) the script by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/nomount.py /mnt/data
   ```

   and try to mount the drive. It should fail.
4. If it works as expected, add it to your friends' account Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add the command:

   ```
   ppython3 /path/to/nomount.py /mnt/data
   ```

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time
import sys
drive = sys.argv[1]
while True:
    check = subprocess.check_output("lsblk").decode("utf-8")
    if drive in check:
        subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "umount", "-l", drive])
    time.sleep(1)
```

#### What the script does

In a loop (once per second), the script checks if the "forbidden" drive is mounted. If so, it will immediately (forcefully) unmount the drive, with the command `umount -f <drivename>`.

#### *Edit*

A bash version of the script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
drive="$1"
while true
do
    if [ -n "$(lsblk | grep $drive)" ]; then
        sudo umount -l $drive
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

Set up and use it similarly to the `python` script, only:

- save it as `nomount.sh`
- run it by the command:

  ```
  sh /path/to/nomount.sh /mnt/data
  ```

  (like the python version; use the drive to make unavailable as an argument)

#### *Edit 2*

About security:

With the right skills and information, practically all solutions can be surpassed. A simple example: with enough time, all solutions would break by simply starting up from a startup usb, unless you encrypted the drive.

In the solution above, the most obvious way would be to open a terminal window, run `ps -u <username>`, look for the process to kill (the script), and kill it. Your friend would however need to have the *skills* to do that, the *intention* to do that and the *knowledge* to suspect that it is done this way.

You can make the process less likely to be recognized, by a few simple additions to the setup:

1. Give the script a disguising name like `unity-desk` (I checked if the name didn't clash with an existing command) *without* extension*
2. Make it executable, to be able to run it without the preceding `sh` or `python3`.

This way, you can run the script with the command:

```
unity-desk /mnt/data
```

In both `ps -u <username>` and `ps -e` the process would be mentioned as `unity-desk`. Not really a process (-name)  you'd likie to kill on first sight.
The command to reveal the fact that it is a script would be to run `ps -ef` which would show the path and the language. However, that would however again be a step further.

Comment: He just doesn't want his wife to have access to his pr0n drive...  ;-)  I would have said to convert the NTFS drive to EXT4, don't make his wife an admin and set security on the directory so that it can only be mounted by one user (and root).  Your solution does not require any conversion so is more elegant so upvoted! ;-)

Comment: @user1007522: Don't thank Jacob!  ;-) If you like his answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like his answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  ;-)

Comment: lol :-) it's not for my prOn. It bothers me that you say this is not very safe..

Comment: I did not upvote or downvoted anything :s.

Comment: I'm going to try your solution because the other one with the groups and stuff don't work. I hope I have some time this evening. No problem you don't need to apologize :-)